# Can't set device to "Use for development"

Tags: iphone, ios

I've doing this many times and never had this problem.
I wanted to develop on a device, and iphone 4 with iOS 7, and after I clicked in the "Organizer" window on "User for Development" it looked like it was doing it, but then right after it finished changing it for development, the button "Use for development" appeared again. And no matter how many times I click its never set to for development.

I tried rebooting the device, closing and opening XCode and still the same thing.

What could be the issue? The device is not jailbreak...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're using Xcode 5, iOS7 development is not supported in previous versions.
2. Click “Add to Member Center” at the bottom of the organizer window instead, and follow those steps.